# WTForm FormField populate values

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have a problem with setting default values of a FieldForm in WTForms.

***models.py***

> ```
> class RepairCategory(db.Model):
>     name = ...
> class Repair(db.Model):
>     price = ..
>     category_id [FK] = ...
>     product_id [FK]
> class Product(db.Model):
>     name = ...
>     description = ...
>     color = ...
> ```

ProductBase contains only attributes which match the Product db Model.
***forms.py***

```
class NewRepair(Form):
    #this is okay - it get's populated
    repair_category = QuerySelectField("Repair category",
                                       query_factory=get_categories)                     
    price = DecimalField()

class ProductBase(Form):
    name = StringField("Name ", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(1, 64)])
    color = StringField("Color ", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(1, 64)])
    description = TextAreaField("Description")
    active = BooleanField()

class Product(Form):
    base_product = FormField(ProductBase)
    add_repairs = FormField(NewRepair)
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

The add_repairs contains a form which I want to use in the view to create Repairs. The base_product is a form to which, ideally, I want to pass a obj=product in the views, so the default values get populated automatically. I want to use the form.populate_obj() as well, just on the base_product form.

here's how I create the Product form in the view:

```
def make_product_form(form=None, product=None, **kwargs):
    form = form()
    form.base_product.obj = product        
    return form
```

And then, when handling POSTs, I want to do:

```
def product(id):
    product = Product.query.get_or_404(id)

    form = make_product_form(form=Product,product=product)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        product_form = form.base_product
        product_form.populate_obj(product)
```

However, the base_form from the Product form, doesn't get filled with default values from an existing object.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? 
Thanks :)

Comment: Doesn't your `make_product_form` function throw `AttributeError` exception? There's no `obj` attribute in your `ProductBase` class so line `form.base_product.obj = product` shouldn't work. You also didn't post code for `EditProduct` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discovering that you can run code directly from the Flask's stack trace in the browser(how cool is that?), I found a solution to my problem.

The key is that when creating the main Product form(in make_product_form()), when I do
`form.base_product.obj` I don't really access the obj attribute.

However, doing `form.base_product.form.process(obj=product)` did the trick! The key is using the base_product.**form** in order to get access to the form within the FormField. 
Here are all the attribututes of form.base_product. The dir() is evaluated just after the form=form() in the make_product_form():

```
dir(form.base_product)
[#ommitted some attributes#, 
'__weakref__', '_formfield', '_obj', '_run_validation_chain', 
'_translations', 'data', 'default', 'description', 
'do_not_call_in_templates', 'errors', 'filters', 'flags', 'form',
'form_class', 'gettext', 'id', 'label', 'meta', 'name', 'ngettext', 
'object_data', 'populate_obj', 'post_validate', 'pre_validate', 
'process', 'process_data', 'process_errors', 'process_formdata', 
'raw_data', 'render_kw', 'separator', 'short_name', 'type', 
'validate', 'validators', 'widget' ]
```

What this shows is that actually form.base_product is a Field, not a Form,and doing form.base_product.form got me the ProductBase form.

Hope this is helpful

****Update****
I had to use the process(obj=product) only on GET requests, to prepopulate the form, otherwise on POST, the actual form data is discarded.

Answer (score 2):

Use form `process` method to populate form fields with object's attributes values.
Use form `populate_obj` method to populate object's attributes with values from form fields.
**Note:** names of object's attributes must match names with form fields.

`process` example:

```
>>> class MyObj(object):
...     name = "object's name"
>>> from wtforms import Form, StringField
>>> class MyForm(Form):
...     name = StringField("Form's name")
>>> my_obj = MyObj()
>>> my_obj.name
"object's name"
>>> my_form = MyForm()
>>> print my_form.name.data
None
>>> my_form.process(obj=my_obj)
>>> my_form.name.data
"object's name"
```

`populate_obj` example:

```
>>> my_form.name.data = "Form's name"
>>> my_form.name.data
"Form's name"
>>> my_obj.name
"object's name"
>>> my_form.populate_obj(my_obj)
>>> my_obj.name
"Form's name"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! :) Your suggestion would work if I had access to the form(so form.base_form). I managed to solve the problem on my own